# Regular expression for math functions

Tags: regex, math

I'm working on ANSI C application, where on input can be something like this `-1 + (3*2) / sin(x^2)`. Allowed must be variable named `x` (no other variables), numerics `0-9`, math operations `+ - * / ^`, brackets `( )` (no other types), and functions `abs, e^x, ln, log, sin, cos, tan, asin, acos, atan, sinh, cosh, tanh`.

Could you help me, how to do this as regular expression? Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with that input? Break it up into its lexical components (`-1`, `+`, `(`, `3`, `*`, ...)? Parse it and evaluate it?

Comment: What about nested parentheses? e.g. `sin((x + 2) / 2)` Regular expressions are not really suited for these kinds of recursive structures.

Comment: Mathematical expressions are not regular, they can't be matched with a regexp. You need a parser.

Comment: I've tried to clear input (remove spaces, control parity), but now I need to check, if whole input is correct and evalue it (enter values for variable x and process it into a field), some of these are clear to me, but I'm stuck on input.

Comment: As said by Barmar, you need to write an parser that can evaluate recursively from the innermost grouping operator. You're on the right track with first sterilizing your input, but from that point, you need to work out evaluating it from the inside out. This recursion should be done prior to breaking it up into it's operator/operand components and evaluating the individually grouped expressions. The best advice I can give is build out a workflow before you start your coding of the parser. Math parsers are a pretty entry level problem, so plan it out and you'll have no problem with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex should work:

```
(?:[0-9-+*/^()x]|abs|e\^x|ln|log|a?(?:sin|cos|tan)h?)+
```

[Explanation here](http://regex101.com/r/nD7jM2).

Comment: @oliv3ra You're welcome! Does this satisfactorily answer your problem?

Comment: It's exactly, what I needed, but I made progress with that, what guys above told me... I started work on my parser for these mathematical expressions, it is better solution of my problem. But I think, it should be useful for me in future for another problem. Once again, thanks. Sorry, I cant vote up, too low rep.